# how to set column name to csv file - c++

Tags: c++, csv

I am writing some string data to a .csv file using `ofstream` like

```
out << string-A << "," <<  string-B << "\n" ;
```

But, I could not find a way to set the column name of the .csv file.

I mean, I want to give column name of string-A to (say) Col-1 and string-B to (say) Col-2.

How to do that in c++ (I don't want to use any libraries). I am working in windows environment.

Edit: I want format like:

```
Col-1         col-2
1              4
2              5
3              6
4              7
```

Column names are headings not cell values ?

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie, but that will give a value in the cells. Not, the heading.

Comment: I don't know what you mean ... you already set string-A and B as column names... you cannot/should not set a 'row name' (whatever that means).

Comment: @alessandro show us your current CSV file and expected file.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, I edited.

Comment: @VoidPointer, I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
out << "Col-1" << "," << "col-2" << "\n";
out << "1"     << "," << "4"     << "\n";
out << "2"     << "," << "5"     << "\n";
out << "3"     << "," << "6"     << "\n";
out << "4"     << "," << "7"     << "\n";
```

Since it is a text file you can write every line, independent of the data (i.e. if it is a header/column name or data row).

However, high likely you want to write the data as a loop, something like:

```
out << "Col-1" << "," << "col-2" << "\n";
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++)
{
    out << x.ToString() << "," << (x + 3).ToString() << "\n";
}
```

Also when reading the data, you want to skip the colum names. To do this, you can skip the first line by default, or you use a 'comment' character like # and skip it dynamically. In this case the output of the file should look like:

```
#Col-1         col-2
1              4
2              5
3              6
4              7
```

and the code to produce this:

```
out << "#Col-1" << "," << "col-2" << "\n";
for (var x = 1; x < 5; x++)
{
    out << x.ToString() << "," << (x + 3).ToString() << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this first:

```
out << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw（20）<< "ROW-1" << setiosflags(ios::left) << setw(20) << "ROW-2" << "\n";
```

Comment: @alessandro you can use setiosflags and setw to control your input!

Answer (score 0):

You can write the names just like you the writing the data. You will have to do this at start.
However depending upon the width of data string you will need to do some formatting so that data is correctly 
aligned below Col-1 and Col-2.

```
out <<"Col-1"<< " "<<"Col-2"<< "\n" ;
```

Comment: You are misunderstanding what CSV does: "Column names are headings not cell values?" You are confusing a simple CSV with a formatted spreadsheet. Other than a simple string on the first line, CSV *has* no 'column names'.